# Exchange,swap or switch

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If someone has something that the other person wants and vice-versa, is it natural to use:

> I **switched** my red scarf for her blue scarf.
>
> I **swapped** my red scarf for her blue scarf.
>
> I **exchanged** my red scarf for her blue scraf.

What sounds more natural:"switch/swap/exchange"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use "switch" or "exchange", but the verb "swap" is specifically targeted for this kind of situation:

> I **swapped** my red scarf **for** her blue scarf.

As James K points out, "swap" automatically implies *mutual consent*, while a "switch" or an "exchange" could be done surreptitiously.

Note I use "swap *for*" not "swap *with*".  This is because you also "swap with" a person, "for" some other object:

> At the beginning of each month all of us roommates have a random drawing to determine chores.  I hate washing windows, so I swapped that **with** Fred **for** mowing the lawn.

It's not wrong to say "swap with", but in my mind this focuses the action on the objects swapped, rather than the exchange with another person.

> Right before going to the cashier, I swapped the red dress **with** the blue dress.

Answer (score 3):

**Exchange** sounds more natural when you take your item back to the store you bought it from. Between two people, I vote for **traded** as as the most natural-sounding word, but swapped or switched is fine, but use "with" as the other answer suggests.

However, there are events called **gift exchanges** where a group of friends each buy a gift and trade them randomly.

Answer (score 2):

I would use "swap", but "exchange" is correct too.  "Switch" is possible but I would prefer one of the other terms.  "Swap" means that we agree to give each other our scarves.  "Switch" could mean that I changed mine with hers, without telling her.

I would use "I swapped my red scarf *with* her blue one".